# Do I need to declare phone/laptop at customs in Japan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan

What about transit airports(France) and airport of departure(Ukraine)?
Do I need to go through customs in these two countries too?

Comment: One can assume you are traveling from Ukraine to Japan. Right?

Comment: Just researching for now. From Kiev, layover in France to Narita in Japan.

Comment: Have the paperwork with you just in case. Back in the day when I started working as a consultant I asked for a form in my home country upon departure in the airport that proved I took it out with me. Cannot remember the details though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, there is no need to declare a laptop or phone in Japan if they are yours and you intend to take them out of the country when you leave.

Your departure and transit airports will not care either, since Customs is focused on importing goods into a country.  (With some exceptions for things like antiques and weaponry, neither of which applies here.)